# Unicode to ASCII is putting spaces in between chars

Tags: powershell, encryption, unicode, encoding, ascii

I have this script to encrypt and decrypt text.

Why is it that when converting the decrypted text byte array to ASCII there is a space in between each character?

```
#Encrypt:

$unencryptedData = "passwordToEncrypt"

$pfxPassword = "P@ssw0rd1"
$certLocation = "D:\Ava\CA\Scripts\Encryption\PFXfiles\f-signed.pfx"
$cert = New-Object 'System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2'($certLocation, $pfxPassword, [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags]::Exportable)
$publicKey = $cert.PublicKey.Key.ToXmlString($false)
$privateKey = $cert.PrivateKey.ToXmlString($true)

$unencryptedDataAsByteArray = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($unencryptedData)

$keySize = 16384
$rsaProvider = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider($keySize)
$rsaProvider.FromXmlString($publicKey)

$encryptedDataAsByteArray = $rsaProvider.Encrypt($unencryptedDataAsByteArray, $false)

$encryptedDataAsString = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($encryptedDataAsByteArray)
Write-Host "Encrypted password = $encryptedDataAsString"

#Decrypt:
$rsaProvider.FromXmlString($privateKey)
$encryptedDataAsByteArray = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($encryptedDataAsString)
$decryptedDataAsByteArray = $rsaProvider.Decrypt($encryptedDataAsByteArray, $false)
$decryptedDataAsString = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString($decryptedDataAsByteArray) 
###### "p a s s w o r d T o E n c r y p t " ###### 
#$decryptedDataAsString = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString($decryptedDataAsByteArray) 
###### "passwordToEncrypt" ###### 

Write-Host "Decrypted password = $decryptedDataAsString"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consult [Character Encodings in the .NET Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404377%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). `[System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode` is UTF-16LE so the character `A` is encoded as the 16-bit value `0x0041`, bytes `0x41 0x00`. `[System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII` is an 8-bit encoding so when you decode `0x41 0x00` with ASCII you get the characters `A` and `NUL` (not space) .

You have to decode your byte array with the same encoding you encoded it in.

Answer (score 2):

In the line:

```
$unencryptedDataAsByteArray = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($unencryptedData)
```

You are setting the unencrypted byte array to a Unicode string. This means 2 bytes in the array for every character in the string. When it is later decrypted, it is still 2 bytes per character.

You need to decrypt it back in reverse order. First, decrypt it back to Unicode. Then, if you need to go to ASCII, use one of the .Net [Encoding.Convert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66sschk1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods.